# createuser could not connect to database postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, configuration, createuser

*Please don't move this question to askubuntu as I think this question is not OS-specific.*

When I invoke the `createuser` postgres command (for now it doesn't matter if I provide any parameters or not), I'm getting this error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Normally it means that the postgres server is down but not this time:

```
pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.4 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log

sudo service postgresql status
9.4/main (port 5432): online
```

But it's true that there is no `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` file because my configuration file (`/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`) has this line:

```
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

So I don't really understand why `createuser` whants to access `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`? Can this path can be hardcoded into the `createuser` binary? I don't see any command line argument to specify the settings file location for `createuser`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The postgresql.conf file is read by the database *server*, but not by client applications (such as createuser, psql, ...).  (In fact, the server configuration file *cannot* be read by client applications because the client would have to connect to the server, which could be halfway across the world, before it could possibly know where that configuration file lives).

Instead, you have to tell your *client* application where to find the socket directory.

If your client application (createuser) is connecting to the local host (which is must be because you are not specifying a different host), you use the host parameter to specify the name of the socket directory.

For example:
    `createuser -h /var/run/postgresql newusername`

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-HOST

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Have you started the service?

```
service postgresql start
```

Comment: This is something that's missing from several tutorials I've been looking into. It may not fix the OP's problem, but it definitely helped me!